# A weird message in CoreBluetooth / CBCentralManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

In my implementation of the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` protocol, I have the following function.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                    didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        return
    }
    ......
    // More useful code irrelevant to the question.
}
```

When the above function is called I can see the message below in the `Xcode` debugging console.

```
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
Error in centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:) :
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The specified device has disconnected from us.}
```

Here is my question:
I must be missing something (because too simple or too subtle), but why does is show an error because "*The specified device has disconnected from us.*"

In the *centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral* function, what else could I expect other than the device being disconnected?

I hope some enlighted expert can bring some light an explain why this is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Apple documentation:
`If the disconnection was not initiated by cancelPeripheralConnection(_:), the cause is detailed in error.`

I.e if You disconnect then you get no error but if They disconnect you see that through the error.
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518791-centralmanager

Comment: OK. Indeed seen like that makes more sense.